# How to convert from react component to arrow function

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I was trying to convert the React component below to arrow function.

```
import { Jsme } from 'jsme'

export default class App extends Component {
  logSmiles(smiles) {
    console.log(smiles)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jsme height="300px" width="400px" options="oldlook,star"  onChange={this.logSmiles}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have tried doing this by converting react component to the arrow function. Need help

```
export const Jsme = () => {
    logSmiles =(smiles)=> {
        console.log(smiles)
      }
  return (
    <div>
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={this.logSmiles}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the `<App />` component, so it would look like this

```
import { Jsme } from 'jsme'

const App = () => {
  const logSmiles = (smiles) => {
    console.log(smiles)
  }

 return (
    <div>
      <Jsme height="300px" width="400px" options="oldlook,star"  onChange={logSmiles}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.logSmiles`?

Comment: good catch, should be `onChange={logSmiles}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
export const Jsme = () => {
    const logSmiles = (smiles) => {
        console.log(smiles)
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Jsme
          height="300px"
          width="400px"
          options="oldlook,star"
          onChange={logSmiles}
        />
      </div>
    );
};
```